# Proving that pole of infinite series "goes to" $+\infty$ or $-\infty$

Tags: limits, roots

Lets define the infinite series:

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^s}{(1-x^k)^2}, \quad s \in \mathbb{N}_0$$

For me, it is clearly to see that it has two poles: at $x = -1$ and at $x = 1$. At the pole, the denominator has a root, so the pole is in general undefined because it would be a division by zero.

If I look at the plot, I can see how the plot behaves if I near from the right or left side to the pole. But is there a relative easy way (like finding the poles) to show that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to -1}f(x) = \begin{cases}+\infty & \text{if } s \text{ is even}\\-\infty & \text{if } s \text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

Comment: That's not a rational function.

Comment: Why not? I can rewrite the expression by an infinity product to have the same denominator. Then denominator is a polynomial and numerator is a polynomial.

Comment: And the actual value of the common denominator is...

Comment: Go on then. @thinkingeye

Comment: PS by the same logic, $\frac{1}{2}$ is rational, $\frac{1}{6}$ is rational, etc, therefore so is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=e$

Comment: Ok, I get it. @obscurans, so at infinity it does not need to be rational. So, should I rename it like "infinite series"?

Comment: Yeah that was @AnginaSeng's point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pull out the common term $x^s$ which does not depend on $k$:

$$f(x)=x^s\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1-x^k)^2}$$

and as long as you know one value of $s$ makes $f(x)$ go to $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow-1$, then clearly increasing $s$ just means multiplying by something close to $-1$, i.e. flipping the sign.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Now, I see. The denominator is always positive because of the square and the whole fraction inside the summation "explodes" to positive infinity as I go close to $x = -1$. And $x^s$ is responsible for the sign of this infinity....like $(-1)^s$.