# How to proof that $f(-1) = -\infty$ for an infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, roots

This question extends question [Prove that pole of infinite series “explodes” to +∞](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3687754/681678) as I wonder if this proof technique still holds when the infinite series is defined as:

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{kx^k}{(1-x^k)^2}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}$$

How to proof that $f(-1) = -\infty$ ?

My attempts would be

$$\lim\limits_{t \to -1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k t^{k-1}}{(1-t^k)^2} = \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} \left[ \lim\limits_{t \to -1} \frac{(2m-1) t^{2m-2}}{(1-t^{2m-1})^2} + \lim\limits_{t \to -1} \frac{2m t^{2m-1}}{(1-t^{2m})^2} \right] = \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{(2m-1)}{4} - \infty \right] = -\infty$$

But I don't think I can do the proof in this way, because of $m \to \infty$.

**EDIT 1:** As DanielWainfleet said, my proof is not working in general. So, how can I proof it?

Comment: $\infty - \infty = 0$ is at best a false statement, and at worse a nonsensical statement. For example, is $\lim_{n\to\infty} n(n-1) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2-n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2-\lim_{n\to\infty} n = \infty - \infty = 0$?

Comment: Ok, I removed this part. But still, how to proof it?

Comment: NEVER assume $\lim_{t\to T}\sum_kF_k(t)=\sum_k \lim_{t\to T}F_k(t).$ It's often false when summing over an infinite set of $k$.

Comment: Hint: If $x=-1$, what is that absolute value of the expression in the summation?  Does it go to zero?

Comment: Well, it depends on $k$. Either it is $-\infty$ or it is $\frac{2m-1}{4}$....like I wrote